# A standard comment for new users asking psak questions

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, new-users

I wanted to suggest that we put forth a standard comment to put on psak questions asked by new users.  The goal of the psak-close reason is, as I understand from various chat conversations, to instill in new users that they should not take what they receive from this site as psak, and to drive this message home we have them edit their question.  I think it could be helpful to have a standard comment to post on these new-users posts.  This occurred to me after posting a very similar comment on two consecutive new questions.

My suggestion is below, and feel free to suggest another or explain if you think this isn't necessary/helpful.

Comment: How is this different from http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1733/759 ?

Comment: @DoubleAA it is specifically addressed to a new user. And doesn't require voting to close to cut and paste it into a comment.

Comment: We should probably include this as an option in http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/190/welcoming-new-users?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've adapted YeZ's [answer](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2251/5323), as per Isaac Moses' [suggestion](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2250/a-standard-comment-for-new-users-asking-psak-questions?cb=1#comment8612_2251), so that *I* could have this here to copy easily. You can copy it also, if you want ;-)

> Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Can you [edit] your question to make it less
>   personal? We [try to avoid practical halachic
>   questions](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734). You might also want to see "[Why is it necessary to ask a
>   rabbi?](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)" for more info.
>   We hope to see you around!

Comment: I like this better.

Comment: @msh210 If you can cut numbers out of a link and they still work, what are they there for in the first place?

Comment: @Shokhet they're there to give you unique referrer links, which feeds the Announcer family of badges.  The last number is a user number and can be dropped.  (Referrals from within the network don't help with those badges anyway.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Ah. Thanks for clarifying that!

Comment: Similar: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3462/5323

Answer (score 6):

> Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Can you [edit] your question to make it less
>   personal? We [try to avoid practical halachic
>   questions](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi).
>   We hope to see you around!

Writing the word [edit] in brackets automatically makes it into a link to edit the post.

Comment: @Scimonster What'd you do???

Comment: @Shokhet I used some <s>magic</s> [practical kabbalah](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1858/community-promotion-ads-2014#comment6818_1863).

Comment: @Scimonster :P No, really....how do you make the links show up normally, without weird line breaks?

Comment: @Shokhet I used HTML entities that create `[` and `(`, so that they don't parse as markdown.

Comment: @Scimonster I should've just figured that out by looking at the revisions history :P ....thanks for explaining! :)

Comment: I think there ought to be a link to http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1734/can-i-consult-mi-yodeya-as-i-would-a-rabbi either instead of or in addition to the one to "Why is it necessary ..."