# Comment templates

Tags: feature-request

I saw a nice idea on [TeX Meta](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks). For some common comments (e.g. welcoming users on the site, suggesting an answer to be accepted) they use previously written codes. I suppose it would be great to have the same on MY. Would you consider posting such codes here?

Comment: we already have a welcome template https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/190/759 and i think a few others scattered around. having them in one place is a reasonable idea though

Comment: @DoubleAA Sorry, I was unaware of that thread. Though, we might add other pieces of code here as you said.

Comment: BTW, the [auto-comments script](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/21539) makes using comment templates much easier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am happy to share some of what I am using, feel free to leverage as is or modify as needed. I believe I copied some of this from @Isaac Moses who originated [the practice of welcoming new users](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/190/11501).

**Standard welcome for a new user**

`[Welcome to Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!`

---

**Welcome for a new user who could benefit from some more reading on how MY is different**

`Welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!`

---

**When a new user uses the answer box for a comment and not an answer**

`Mi Yodeya isn't like a standard internet discussion forum – we're strictly a Q&A site, where we expect answers to answer the question at hand. As it is, this reads more like a comment. As such it might be removed or converted to a comment beneath the question. I hope you can find other questions to answer, or questions you would like to ask.`

---

**If someone can benefit from the tour (i.e., new user doesn't have any badge)**

`Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?`

`Hello and welcome to Mi Yodeya. MY is putting significant emphasis on sources since we don't really know you. If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.`

---

**If a new user hasn't registered yet**

`[Welcome to Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501)  Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting. Great to have you learn with us!`

---

**Good ending for any question regarding CYLOR**

`Of course, [consult your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146) before implementing anything [you learn here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734).`

---

**Recommend an answer to be accepted**

`Have you considered [accepting this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?`

---

**Asking user to avoid excess use of jargon**

`For the sake of outsiders, we try to avoid [unnecessary jargon](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1606/site-policy-on-jargon) at Mi Yodeya. If possible, please try to find an English equivalent to make your post more understandable.`